# Korban Tamid: why is "from Sinai" after the lamb and meal offering, but before the wine offering?

Tags: korban, shacharis-morning-prayer

In the Korban Tamid (Bamidbar 28:1-8), it states,

"The one lamb shalt thou offer in the morning, and the other lamb shalt thou offer at dusk; and the tenth part of an ephah of fine flour for a meal-offering, mingled with the fourth part of a hin of beaten oil. **It is a continual burnt-offering, which was offered in Mount Sinai**... And the drink-offering thereof shall be the fourth part of a hin for the one lamb; in the holy place shalt thou pour out a drink-offering of strong drink..."

What reason is there for the lamb/meal offering being described as at Sinai, but the wine offering is mentioned afterwards?

Every day we read this, but I'm perplexed... this will drive me to drink.

Comment: A word of advice- though these pesukim are read as part of Shacharit, save the drinking until after Maariv ;)

Comment: Thanks, it won't be too great a sacrifice to wait.

Comment: If you're really yayin' to have some a glass of red at lunch is OK as far as the Rambam is concerned, @DrMoishe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drink away! See the [Malbim (ibid)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.28.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Malbim_on_Numbers.28.6.1&lang2=bi) who points to various locations in the Talmud that discuss this same issue.

Some Tanaim learn from your question - why Har Sinai is mentioned before wine libations -  that the **wine libations were not offered in the desert**, others learn that they were already **offered wine libations in the desert and they didn't wait until they entered the land of Israel to start** wine libations.

> עלת תמיד העשויה בהר סיני ת"ק הוא ר"ע (כמ"ש בספרי זוטא) לשטתו שס"ל בקדושין (דף לז) **שקרבו נסכים במדבר** וע"כ ס"ל שעולת הר סיני [שהיתה ג"כ עולת תמיד לדידיה כמ"ש. בחגיגה דף ו'] טעונה נסכים, וריה"ג סובר כר' ישמעאל **שלא קרבו נסכים במדבר** לכן ס"ל שעולת הר סיני [אע"ג שגם לדידיה היתה עולת תמיד כמ"ש בחגיגה שם] א"צ נסכים שעדיין לא היה במת צבור עד שנעשה המשכן ועמ"ש בפי' הספרי שלח (סי' א'):‏